# Python telegram bot doesn't execute actions operations

Tags: python, telegram-bot, python-telegram-bot

**I made this code to display buttons on /start.**

```
from telegram import InlineKeyboardButton, InlineKeyboardMarkup
from telegram.ext import Updater, CommandHandler, CallbackQueryHandler, ConversationHandler
MENU, HELP = range(2)

def start(bot, update):
    keyboard = [
                 [InlineKeyboardButton('Help', callback_data='help')]
               ]

    # Create initial message:
    message = 'Welcome.'

    update.message.reply_text(message, reply_markup=InlineKeyboardMarkup(keyboard))

def help(bot, update):

    keyboard = [
                 [InlineKeyboardButton('Leave', callback_data='cancel')]
               ]


    bot.edit_message_text(
    text='Help ... help..',
    chat_id=update.callback_query.message.chat_id,
    message_id=update.callback_query.message.message_id,
    reply_markup=InlineKeyboardMarkup(keyboard)
)
    bot.answer_callback_query(update.callback_query.id, text='')

def cancel(bot, update):

    bot.edit_message_text(
    text='Bye',
    chat_id=update.callback_query.message.chat_id,
    message_id=update.callback_query.message.message_id,
)
    bot.answer_callback_query(update.callback_query.id, text='')

    return ConversationHandler.END     


# Create the EventHandler and pass it your bot's token.
updater = Updater(token="tokencode", use_context=True)

# Get the dispatcher to register handlers:
dispatcher = updater.dispatcher

dispatcher.add_handler(CommandHandler('start', start))
dispatcher.add_handler(CallbackQueryHandler(help, pattern='help'))
dispatcher.add_handler(CallbackQueryHandler(cancel, pattern='cancel'))

updater.start_polling()

updater.idle()
```

**The code works because if we write some debugging print("hi") in the methods and we execute the bot, we will see that we enter in those methods. Neverthless buttons or messages doesn't show.**

The result of the code should be this, but doesn't work like this 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/c0wyM.gif

I'm on this since many hours, so any help is appreciated.

Comment: Can you help me understand the sentence you have written in bold at the bottom?

Answer (score 0):

You have to switch the parameters in the definition of the functions. In addition to this I'd rather call `context` what you've call `bot`.

Here the code that works

```py
import os
from telegram import InlineKeyboardButton, InlineKeyboardMarkup
from telegram.ext import Updater, CommandHandler, CallbackQueryHandler, ConversationHandler
MENU, HELP = range(2)

def start(update, bot):
    keyboard = [
                 [InlineKeyboardButton('Help', callback_data='help')]
               ]

    # Create initial message:
    message = 'Welcome.'

    update.message.reply_text(message, reply_markup=InlineKeyboardMarkup(keyboard))

def help(update, context):

    keyboard = [
                 [InlineKeyboardButton('Leave', callback_data='cancel')]
               ]


    context.bot.edit_message_text(
    text='Help ... help..',
    chat_id=update.callback_query.message.chat_id,
    message_id=update.callback_query.message.message_id,
    reply_markup=InlineKeyboardMarkup(keyboard)
)
    context.bot.answer_callback_query(update.callback_query.id, text='')

def cancel(update, context):

    context.bot.edit_message_text(
    text='Bye',
    chat_id=update.callback_query.message.chat_id,
    message_id=update.callback_query.message.message_id,
)
    context.bot.answer_callback_query(update.callback_query.id, text='')

    return ConversationHandler.END     


# Create the EventHandler and pass it your bot's token.
updater = Updater(token="tokencode", use_context=True)

# Get the dispatcher to register handlers:
dispatcher = updater.dispatcher

dispatcher.add_handler(CommandHandler('start', start))
dispatcher.add_handler(CallbackQueryHandler(help, pattern='help'))
dispatcher.add_handler(CallbackQueryHandler(cancel, pattern='cancel'))

updater.start_polling()

updater.idle()
```